# Unable to install windows from usb flash, I get an error "setup was unable to create new system partition"

Tags: windows, usb, installation, system, partition

I have CD with window 7, I can install windows from this cd, but disc is't mine.
 So, I want to make a copy on my usb flash drive. I made iso copy of cd disc with WinISO, then I wrote this iso file on my flash drive with "Iso to Usb".

Now I try to install windows from this flash. I have 1tb hdd, I created 100gb partition and get 100gb partition, but when I did the same with with Windows cd disc, it creates 100 gb primary partition and 100 mb system partition.

So, when I tried to install windows in 100 gb partition from cd it installed, but when I tried to install from usb I got exception: "setup was unable to create new system partition".

Why so? Why I do the same steps and I can install from cd, but can't install from usb?
Why usb windows didn't create system partition? And how to fix it?

Comment: I can install windows 8 from flash drive with no problems. But Windows 7 I've tried to install from two different ISOs but still the same problem. Even if I installed win 8, I have system partition and 100 gb partition with win 8, and then I try to install win 7 on the same partition, I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

When installing using a flash-drive perform the following steps:

Step by step instruction:

1. When the boot setup starts from USB drive
2. Press Shift+F10
3. The command prompt will open.
4. In console type **diskpart.exe** and press enter. In this program execute following:

   1. select disk=0. Disk 0 is your destination drive, so be careful, all information on this drive will be removed.
   2. create partition primary size=xxx, where xxx – is the size of new partition
   3. select partition=1
   4. active
   5. format fs=ntfs quick
   6. assign
   7. exit

4.exit
5.Now close the setup and restart.

This should solve your problem as it did mine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows usually creates a partition with enought space for the system.
You can try to just take the 1tb HDD as target for installation, and windows will create a partition automatically.

Otherwise, your ISO-Copy may be corrupted.
You could easily download the ISO-Files from [here](http://www.chip.de/artikel/Windows-7-Neu-installieren-mit-kostenlosem-ISO-2_46353200.html).

3. Option: Make a Copy of the CD and try with that one?

Answer (score 0):

Having installed windows 7 from a USB drive many times, I've found that if you're trying to install using a USB 3.0 flash drive, then you will get the "setup was unable to create new system partition" error message.

Since I couldn't find any solutions to this at the time, I was fiddling with everything to try to make it work. Eventually I found out an interesting (but strange) solution:

1. Go through the install process until you get to the screen that asks you to select a partition for the windows installation
2. Make sure your desired partition is listed, and that its formatted correctly
3. Unplug the USB drive
4. Press 'Refresh' (ONCE) to refresh the partition list/window (ONLY press refresh)
5. Plug the USB drive back in (use the same port as before)
6. Select the destination partition for the Windows installation, and try to begin the installation

I've done this a few times now on different machines, and it's worked like a charm.

I believe it has something to do with Windows 7 not natively supporting USB 3.0 and/or USB drives with SSD controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is probably seeing the USB drive as the main hard drive, because you have probably made it the first boot device in the BIOS. This will result in Windows trying to install to the install drive.

To solve this problem, make the internal HDD the first boot device, then press `F12` or whatever key for boot device selection your BIOS requires.